# Best way to form submit using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two methods for this -

```
<body onLoad="document.frmconfirm.submit();">
  <form name="frmconfirm" action="https://abc.com/" method="post">
    <input type='hidden' name='account_id' value='5715' />
  </form>
</body>
```

and

```
<form id='subFrm' name='subFrm' method='post' action='https://abc.com'>
   <input type='hidden' name='msg' value='dummy'>
</form>
<script>document.subFrm.submit();</script>
```

I am getting some issue on firefox in second one.

I would love to hear your thoughts and any other full proof approach.

I need to automate this process on a page, so can't use jQuery.

Comment: Wait, why is jQuery not an option?

Comment: You can't use jQuery, but you can use JavaScript, which jQuery is?  -- jQuery would be overkill, but your reasoning doesn't make sense

Comment: We are getting some issues at Firefox 3.6 for redirection. It was just for the good discussion. I like the first approach.

Answer (score 1):

What are "some issues"?

Your two snippets of html/javascript should be pretty much identical in their functionality. The first is probably preferable in any case as the javascript runs when the page fully loads. The second runs some javascript directly as it is parsed, which should work fine as long as, as in your second example, the form has already been parsed.

TL;DR - They're (pretty much) the same.

Comment: I'd just like to add that I prefer the second approach, with a script tag directly after the form. This makes the form submit as soon as possible, especially if there are more script tags, html and css below the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<form id='subFrm' name='subFrm' method='post' action='https://abc.com'>
   <input type='hidden' name='msg' value='dummy'>
</form>
<script>document.getElementById("subFrm").submit();</script>
```

or

```
<form id='subFrm' name='subFrm' method='post' action='https://abc.com'>
   <input type='hidden' name='msg' value='dummy'>
</form>
<script>window.onload = new function() { document.getElementById("subFrm").submit() };</script>
```

You could use jQuery to do this btw :)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#subFrm").submit()
}
```